# Table width bug

Tags: tables, tabularx, pdfsync

I'd like my table to look like it does in the top picture. If I delete either LINE-A, or LINE-B, in the code below, it works. If I leave them both there, however, it results in the wrong width of the table (bottom picture). Note that neither LINE-A nor LINE-B should ideally have any impact on the MWE, although I suppose tabularx is likely to redefine elements involved with the standard table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx} % LINE-A
\usepackage{pdfsync}  % LINE-B

\begin{document}

\chapter{fawef}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l p{3cm}}
            \hline
            fawe & fawfe fawef fawhpfh faw fehpawfe aw efawep fapw efa wefpawef ap wefpaowhefpaiwe f afwefp awfehpawef \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: Right]

[image: Wrong]

### EDIT 1

Thanks for your answers. Both of you pointed to pdfsync as the culprit. So I tried removing pdfsync from the bigger (than MWE) document, and it turned out that it makes no difference then. That is, tabularx still breaks the table.

Comment: Comment on your "Edit 1" posting: Please post the full preamble of your bigger document. Without that information, it's going to be impossible to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: Don't load `pdfsync`; it is obsolete.

Comment: You should look at the package `epigraph`.

Comment: Aren't you perhaps looking for the `epigraph` package?

Comment: If this layout is an epigraph as part of the chapter head it should not be in `\begin{table}` as you do not want it to float, just delete `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}`

Comment: Sorry, I am not wanting the epigraph layout. The output is just looks like it for the MWE. @Mico, yes I know I should. But I found a workaround using only `tabular`, so I think I will just leave it at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation you should use the `[novbox]` package option:

> In case of severe conflicts with another package, try instead
>
> `\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}`

[image: output]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx} % LINE-A
\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}  % LINE-B

\begin{document}

\chapter{fawef}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l p{3cm}}
            \hline
            fawe & fawfe fawef fawhpfh faw fehpawfe aw efawep fapw efa wefpawef ap wefpaowhefpaiwe f afwefp awfehpawef \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `pdfsync` package is obsolete; it fills TeX file with whatsits and the DVI/PDF file with specials for synchronization, but SyncTeX does way better! The simplest thing is avoiding `pdfsync`.

Answer (score 3):

With modern TeX installations, you shouldn't use `pdfsync` at all as support is now embedded into pdfTeX and XeTeX. See the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfsync/README).